# How to focus on certain field when tabbing to next record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a Form of the following structure:
The ***Main form***, and within it, a ***Subform***, in which I enter the data.
The subform has two fields (Species, Abundance)

I insert the data inside the subform, using tab to move between the two fields (which works as it should) - **The tab order is correct**

**The Problem is**:
When I finish to enter the last record, I use tab to go to the next record in the *Main form*. But the focus in the subform is on the *Abundance* field, instead of the *Species* field.

How can I set the focus on the *Species* field when moving to the next record in the main form (using tab)?

**Pictues:**

[image: When I reach the last record in the Subform:]

[image: Focus is on wrong field]

**First picture:** I'm in the last record in the Subform, and then press TAB.
**Second Picture:** After pressing TAB, I'm at the next record in the Main form, but the focused field in the subform is *Abundance* instead of *species*.

I want to note that the tab order is correct - (Species is first, Abundance is second)

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but you may be able to do something with the OnGotFocus event of the ID control on the main form to set the focus to the proper control in your subform.  I don't think you can use the BeforeUpdate, AfterUpdate, Dirty or Change events, because your ID isn't changing.  I can't think of any event off the top of my head that gets fired when you move from record to record.  Unless you use a bookmark, maybe.  HansUp, Gord or Andre might know better, if one of them chimes in.